# how to apply while loop for loop query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test4`()
BEGIN
declare  GroupArray  text;
DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE loopcount INT DEFAULT 0;
declare GroupId varchar (5);

set GroupArray=(select group_concat(distinct groupId) from EventList_View);

SET loopcount = (SELECT LENGTH(GroupArray) - 
    LENGTH(REPLACE(GroupArray,',', '')));
 select loopcount;
    WHILE i <= loopcount DO
        SET i = i + 1;
        SET GroupId = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GroupArray,
        ',', i),',', -1));
      select GroupId;

    END WHILE;  


END
```

this is my query i am trying to  apply while loop and i want get all groupId  but GroupArray [1,2,3]i am getting value but in loop count i  am getting 0 can any one please tell me where am doing wrong . why i am unable to get loop count null and why i am not getting value 1,2,3 for group

Comment: your procedure is fine it may be problem with your query.

Comment: you don't need an SP for this. Please post your real solution. As @drew says, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @jaidutt  please tell me where am doing wrong then why its not coming

Comment: select group_concat(distinct groupId) from EventList_View what this query return

Comment: its retrun "1,2,3,0"